# C# Visual Studio 2015 - Automatic jump into brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so here goes:

I've got this annoying problem/feature in Visual Studio 2015. The problem is every time I create an if statement, for, while, etc. with autocomplete (tab-tab). When I then go to the line of the end bracket and try to create a new line (simple press of Enter) right after it, my text cursor will immediately jump into the brackets, instead of making a new line.

I've looked far an wide as for trying to disable this "feature" as it is incredibly annoying. But I have not been able to find any information on it anywhere, so now I am asking you all this question.

Thank you!

**How I produce the problem:**

1. Anywhere in a C# project, make a new if statement (while, for, etc. can be used too).
2. Navigate to just after the end bracket.
3. Press Enter to make a new line.
4. The marker will have jumped to the inside of the statement, instead of making a new line.

Comment: Are you typing `if`and follow by `TAB` key? If yes, then you are using a snippet. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9ybhaktf(v=vs.100).aspx how to manage snippets. You can remove `if` snippet if it annoys you too much.

Comment: I just tried it and cannot reproduce your problem. Trailmax might be on the right track: if you are using the 'if' snippet using TAB no matter where you are ENTER always places the cursor between the brackets.

Comment: Only able to repro when tab-completing the `if` snippet... if you write `if(){}` manually, this doesn't occur. Also doesn't matter where you move the cursor, the first `[enter]` press after tab-completing the snippet drops you into the body

Comment: Using only spaces when typing: http://imgur.com/q8ZDS2s

Comment: trailmax, Sergio, Mathias.
It seems to be exactly this!
But I have no idea how to disable the cursor move on press of Enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'problem' is that when using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key you are activating the snippets feature. After typing <kbd>tab</kbd> you are in 'snippet editing' mode, where each <kbd>tab</kbd> (and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>) are used to navigate the *placeholders* defined by the snippet. In snippet mode, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key always takes you wherever the person who designed the snippet thought it was the best place to leave the cursor after that snippet. For the `if` snippet that happens to be inside the brackets.

The good news is that you can create your own snippets, and even modify existing snippets to change their behaviour. However, as far as I know this involves manually editing snippet definition files (xml files) or using external extensions. For example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/01/15/visually-creating-snippets.aspx

As a workaround, you can also just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit snippet editing mode before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.